# StructureMap 'conditional singleton' for Lucene.Net IndexReader

Tags: c#, singleton, structuremap, ioc-container, lucene.net

I have a threadsafe object that is expensive to create and needs to be available through my application (a Lucene.Net IndexReader).

The object can become invalid, at which point I need to recreate it (IndexReader.IsCurrent is false, need a new instance using IndexReader.Reopen).

I'd like to able to use an IoC container (StructureMap) to manage the creation of the object, but I can't work out if this scenario is possible.  It feels like some kind of "conditional singleton" lifecycle.

Does StructureMap provide such a feature?
Any alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use a scope of `PerRequest` and not return the `IndexReader` directly.  Instead, I'd return an abstraction of the `IndexReader` which would perform a check on a static reference held on the class level.

Then, when your property on the shim/proxy/abstraction is accessed, it would check the static reference (you would make it thread-safe, of course) and re-get the `IndexReader` if needed before delivering it back to the user.

Comment: I agree with casperOne. Think about hiding the instance behind an interface / facade so you can more easily implement strategies such as object pooling.

Comment: I considered this, but it feels a shame to be removing resposibiliy for object creation and lifetime management away from the IoC container. It will definitely work for me and will be my fall back solution if I don't come up with anything more IoC centric.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I have gone for a simple proxy object that wraps the actual IndexReader and manages the Reopening.  As I need to use the same instance of this across requests I am using StructureMap to provide a singleton instance of it.  Code below.

I've investigated creating a custom StructureMap ILifecycle to handle this situation, but didn't get to far, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4956821/3580).

```
public class IndexReaderProxy
{
    private IndexReader _indexReader;
    private readonly object _indexReaderLock = new object();

    public IndexReaderProxy(Directory directory, bool readOnly)
    {
        _indexReader = IndexReader.Open(directory, readOnly);
    }

    public IndexReader GetCurrentIndexReader()
    {
        ReopenIndexReaderIfNotCurrent();
        return _indexReader;
    }

    private void ReopenIndexReaderIfNotCurrent()
    {
        if (_indexReader.IsCurrent()) return;
        lock (_indexReaderLock)
        {
            if (_indexReader.IsCurrent()) return;
            var newIndexReader = _indexReader.Reopen();
            _indexReader.Close();
            _indexReader = newIndexReader;
        }
    }
}
```

And the StructureMap registration:

```
For<IndexReaderProxy>().Singleton().Use(
            new IndexReaderProxy(FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(LuceneIndexPath)), true)
        );
```

Comment: Content should probably be merged with the question.

Comment: The first

if (_indexReader.IsCurrent()) return;

outside of the lock can throw a Lucene.Net.Store.AlreadyClosedException, which should be caught.

When this thread can enter the lock, the IndexReader has been opened again on the current index.