# StructureMap - Can the state of cached entity be inspected in a custom ILifecycle?

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

I'm spiking a custom StructureMap ILifecycle with semantics similar to the SingletonLifecycle but with a predicate that must be met for the existing instance to be returned.

The idea is that the custom lifecycle class will take a predicate as a constructor parameter, and that if the predicate is not met then a new empty cache will be returned.  So far I've based the code on the existing SingletonLifecycle but can see no way of inspecting the state of the cached entity.

- From within an ILifecycle is it
  possible to retrieve and inspect the
  cached entity?
- StructureMap folks - is this even a valid approach?

Code so far is as follows:

```
public class PredicatedLifecycle<T> : ILifecycle
{
    public PredicatedLifecycle(Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        Predicate = predicate;
    }

    private Predicate<T> Predicate { get; set; }
    private readonly MainObjectCache _cache = new MainObjectCache();

    public void EjectAll()
    {
        _cache.DisposeAndClear();
    }

    public IObjectCache FindCache()
    {
        // TODO : Inspect the cache for an instance of T
        // if it exists retrieve from the cache and invoke 
        // the predicate against it
        // replace the cache if predicate returns false
        return _cache;
    }

    public string Scope
    {
        get { return GetType().Name; }
    }
}
```